# How to apply the describe function after grouping a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to find the cleanest way to apply the `describe` function to a grouped DataFrame (this question can also grow to apply any DF function to a grouped DF)

I tested grouped aggregate pandas UDF with no luck. There's always a way of doing it by passing each statistics inside the `agg` function but that's not the proper way.

If we have a sample dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))
```

The idea would be to do something similar to Pandas:

```py
df.groupby("id").describe()
```

where the result would be:

```py
                                                   v
    count mean     std    min   25%    50%  75%   max
id                              
1   2.0   1.5   0.707107  1.0   1.25   1.5  1.75  2.0
2   3.0   6.0   3.605551  3.0   4.00   5.0  7.50  10.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way around passing each statistic to the `agg` function. That is the proper (and only) way.

Comment: val df = myDataFrame.describe();                                                                          df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [summary: string, count: string] ;                      df.show()

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```py
df = (df
    .groupby("id")
    .agg(F.count('v').alias('count'),
         F.mean('v').alias('mean'),
         F.stddev('v').alias('std'),
         F.min('v').alias('min'),
         F.expr('percentile(v, array(0.25))')[0].alias('%25'),
         F.expr('percentile(v, array(0.5))')[0].alias('%50'),
         F.expr('percentile(v, array(0.75))')[0].alias('%75'),
         F.max('v').alias('max')))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+----+------------------+---+----+---+----+----+
| id|count|mean|               std|min| %25|%50| %75| max|
+---+-----+----+------------------+---+----+---+----+----+
|  1|    2| 1.5|0.7071067811865476|1.0|1.25|1.5|1.75| 2.0|
|  2|    3| 6.0| 3.605551275463989|3.0| 4.0|5.0| 7.5|10.0|
+---+-----+----+------------------+---+----+---+----+----+
```

Comment: This works, but I would like a cleaner way of doing it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a utility function module you could put something like this in it and call a one liner afterwards.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def groupby_apply_describe(df, groupby_col, stat_col):
    """From a grouby df object provide the stats
    of describe for each key in the groupby object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : spark dataframe groupby object
    col : column to compute statistics on
    
    """
    output = df.groupby(groupby_col).agg(
        F.count(stat_col).alias("count"),
        F.mean(stat_col).alias("mean"),
        F.stddev(stat_col).alias("std"),
        F.min(stat_col).alias("min"),
        F.expr(f"percentile({stat_col}, array(0.25))")[0].alias("%25"),
        F.expr(f"percentile({stat_col}, array(0.5))")[0].alias("%50"),
        F.expr(f"percentile({stat_col}, array(0.75))")[0].alias("%75"),
        F.max(stat_col).alias("max"),
    )
    print(output.orderBy(groupby_col).show())
    return output
```

In your case you would call `groupby_apply_describe(df, 'id', 'v')`. The output should match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

### Describe multiple columns...

Inspired by the answer before, but tested in `spark/3.0.1`

```py
import itertools as it
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce

group_column = 'id'
metric_columns = ['v','v1','v2']

# You will have a dataframe with df variable

def spark_describe(group_col, stat_col):
    return df.groupby(group_col).agg(
        F.count(stat_col).alias(f"{stat_col}_count"),
        F.mean(stat_col).alias(f"{stat_col}_mean"),
        F.stddev(stat_col).alias(f"{stat_col}_std"),
        F.min(stat_col).alias(f"{stat_col}_min"),
        F.max(stat_col).alias(f"{stat_col}_max"),
        F.expr(f"percentile({stat_col}, array(0.25))")[0].alias(f"{stat_col}_25pct"),
        F.expr(f"percentile({stat_col}, array(0.5))")[0].alias(f"{stat_col}_50pct"),
        F.expr(f"percentile({stat_col}, array(0.75))")[0].alias(f"{stat_col}_75pct"),   
    )

_join = lambda a,b: a.join(b, group_column, 'inner')
dff = reduce(_join, list(map(lambda x: spark_describe(*x), zip(it.repeat(group_column, len(metric_columns)), metric_columns))))
```