# Weighted mean median quartiles in Spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, median, weighted-average, quartile

I have a Spark SQL dataframe:

| id | Value | Weights |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | 9 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |

I need to `groupBy` by 'id' and aggregate to get the ***weighted* mean, median, and quartiles** of the values per 'id'. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: please edit the question and paste the expected output

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083814/how-to-apply-the-describe-function-after-grouping-a-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: perhaps this is useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368511/4758823

Answer (score 3):

Before the calculation you should do a small transformation to your `Value` column:

```
F.explode(F.array_repeat('Value', F.col('Weights').cast('int')))
```

- `array_repeat` creates an array out of your number - the number inside the array will be repeated as many times as is specified in the column 'Weights' (casting to int is necessary, because `array_repeat` expects this column to be of int type. After this part the first value of `2` will be transformed into `[2,2,2,2]`.
- Then, `explode` will create a row for every element in the array. So, the line `[2,2,2,2]` will be transformed into 4 rows, each containing an integer `2`.
- Then you can calculate statistics, the results will have weights applied, as your dataframe is now transformed according to the weights.

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 2, 4),
     (1, 5, 2),
     (2, 1, 4),
     (2, 6, 2),
     (2, 9, 4),
     (3, 2, 4)],
    ['id', 'Value', 'Weights']
)

df = df.select('id', F.explode(F.array_repeat('Value', F.col('Weights').cast('int'))))
df = (df
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(F.mean('col').alias('weighted_mean'),
         F.expr('percentile(col, 0.5)').alias('weighted_median'),
         F.expr('percentile(col, 0.25)').alias('weighted_lower_quartile'),
         F.expr('percentile(col, 0.75)').alias('weighted_upper_quartile')))
df.show()
#+---+-------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
#| id|weighted_mean|weighted_median|weighted_lower_quartile|weighted_upper_quartile|
#+---+-------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
#|  1|          3.0|            2.0|                    2.0|                   4.25|
#|  2|          5.2|            6.0|                    1.0|                    9.0|
#|  3|          2.0|            2.0|                    2.0|                    2.0|
#+---+-------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```