# how to estimate basic statistics group of data with spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, statistics

I have a table which is similar with the sample below:

```
id     value      group
a        2         0
b        3         0
c        4         0
d        6         0
e        4         0
f        3         1
g        2         1
h        1         1
i        0         1
j        3         1
```

The `group` column is a sign for each data group. From 0 to 0 is a sign for the first group, and so also with from 1 to 1 is also a sign for the second group. I want to create a new table which is the result of basic statistic (mean, median, st.deviation, variance, etc) estimation of each group.

One thing that I realize is I need to aggregate them first in order to estimate the basic statistic.

The desired table would be like this:

```
group   max    min    mean    median    stdt    var
0        6      2     3,8      
1        3      0
2
```

How should I write my spark sql to get the desired result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply the describe function after grouping a PySpark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083814/how-to-apply-the-describe-function-after-grouping-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62367457/14165730) in Spark SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
import spark.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sourceDF = Seq(
  ("a", 2, 0),
  ("b", 3, 0),
  ("c", 4, 0),
  ("d", 6, 0),
  ("e", 4, 0),
  ("f", 3, 1),
  ("g", 2, 1),
  ("h", 1, 1),
  ("i", 0, 1),
  ("j", 3, 1)
).toDF("id","value","group")

val resDF = sourceDF
  .groupBy("group")
  .agg(max("value")
  , min("value")
  , mean("value")
  )

resDF.show(false)
//  +-----+----------+----------+----------+
//  |group|max(value)|min(value)|avg(value)|
//  +-----+----------+----------+----------+
//  |1    |3         |0         |1.8       |
//  |0    |6         |2         |3.8       |
//  +-----+----------+----------+----------+
```